# Take system time and convert to season to display information in Java

Tags: java, android, time

I am working on my first project in android studio using Java and have gotten lost.  The app I am working on has a button (that works) that will go to a new activity.  Depending on the user selection, I would like the new activity to display data by season.  For example, if I click on NY and say submit, the new activity would show the New York Knicks if system time says it's fall, or Yankees in Spring, etc.  The only problem is I have no idea where to start and google searching has led to nothing.  I'm coming from Python and am basically just trying to teach myself more languages for better opportunities but haven't been that lucky in java.  Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the question is a bit vague. So, do you know 1) how to get the current date in Java/Android 2) How to compare that date to a specific date (like your chosen date for the spring season start) 3) what would be the "minimum API level" i.e. the lowest Android version that you'd like to support? The third point has some effect on what kind of date APIs you'll have easily available. The newer ones supported by the more recent Android versions are much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this :

```
public enum Season {
    Winter,
    Spring,
    Summer,
    Fall
}

public Season getSeason(int dayOfYear) {
    // define "day of year" ranges for the northern hemisphere
    final int DAY_SPRING_MIN = 80;
    final int DAY_SPRING_MAX = 172;
    final int DAY_SUMMER_MIN = DAY_SPRING_MAX;
    final int DAY_SUMMER_MAX = 264;
    final int DAY_FALL_MIN = DAY_SUMMER_MAX;
    final int DAY_FALL_MAX = 355;

    Season result = Season.Winter;
    if (dayOfYear > DAY_SPRING_MIN && dayOfYear <= DAY_SPRING_MAX) {
        result = Season.Spring;
    } else if (dayOfYear > DAY_SUMMER_MIN && dayOfYear <= DAY_SUMMER_MAX) {
        result = Season.Summer;
    } else if (dayOfYear > DAY_FALL_MIN && dayOfYear <= DAY_FALL_MAX) {
        result = Season.Fall;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and call it :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentDayOfYear = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
Log.e("Season", "current season : " + getSeason(currentDayOfYear));
```

I advice you to check my values by the way ^^